# How can I type a function that takes an arbitrary number of input functions such that its return type can be determined?

Tags: typescript

I have a `waterfall` function that takes in a list of functions and an initial value, and passes the return value of each function to the next one. The return type of the `waterfall` function is the return value of the last provided function.

```
function waterfall(
    fns: ((...args: any[]) => unknown)[],
    init?: unknown
): Promise<unknown> {
    if (!fns.length) {
        return Promise.resolve(init);
    }
    return fns.reduce(async (promise, nextFn) => {
        const args = await promise;
        return nextFn(args);
    }, Promise.resolve(init));
}

(async () => {
    const resultAsync = await waterfall(
        [
            x => Promise.resolve(x + 1),
            x => Promise.resolve(x * 2)
        ],
        42
    ); // 86
    const resultSync = await waterfall(
        [x => x + 1, x => x * 2],
        42
    ); // 86
    console.log({ resultAsync, resultSync });
})();
```

How can I type the `waterfall` function so that the return type can be correctly determined by the provided functions?

Answer (score 2):

The function you are describing is just a variant of the function generally known as `compose`, for doing [function composition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_composition). As far as I know, the type of `compose` is only possible to approximate with overloaded type definitions in TypeScript.

For an example see [the source for the compose function in Redux](https://github.com/reduxjs/redux/blob/195b446cfad4833a3304c6d4afbdb3ac50a1b435/src/compose.ts), of which the essential part is this:

```
type Func<T extends any[], R> = (...a: T) => R

/* no functions */
function compose(): <R>(a: R) => R

/* one function */
function compose<F extends Function>(f: F): F

/* two functions */
function compose<A, T extends any[], R>(
  f1: (a: A) => R,
  f2: Func<T, A>
): Func<T, R>

/* three functions */
function compose<A, B, T extends any[], R>(
  f1: (b: B) => R,
  f2: (a: A) => B,
  f3: Func<T, A>
): Func<T, R>

// And so on...
```

Note that while this may not be elegant, it does actually work pretty well. Especially if you can be a bit more strict than Redux can be, and omit the more general type definitions, as I have above.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but I believe specifying arity in this way would prevent me from passing in arrays of functions, since those are of arbitrary length.

Comment: If you for some reason need to wrap your function arguments in an array (or rather a tuple if you want type checking), just instead do the same with tuples, e.g.: `function arrCompose<A, B, T extends any[], R>([f1: (b: B) => R, f2: (a: A) => B, f3: Func<T, A>]): Func<T, R>`

Comment: Or if you actually want to build arrays of varying functions of unknown length at runtime, that is unfortunately by definition not type-checkable.

Comment: I guess it's worth mentioning, non-varying functions of course works: `function arrCompose<R>(fns: Array<(x: R) => R>): (x: R) => R`